# iAd not appearing in modal view

Tags: objective-c, iad, adbannerview

I have a view controller that uses iAd banners. I have implemented iAds in this view just as I have in other working views.

When segueing to this view controller using PUSH, the iAd dispalys itself correctly. However, when segueing using MODAL, the iAd banner does not render. I have imported the iAd framework and added

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

to my viewDidLoad. Is there something I'm unaware of when using iAds in a view presented modally?

Thanks!